# JavaScript - enter URL

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm doing a POST form submit which opens a new tab with a HTML page on a different domain. Initially, the HTML page throws a 404. If I manually refresh, same thing.

However, if I focus on the address bar and hit ENTER the page loads fine...

So are there any JS methods to open a new tab, set the URL, and hit ENTER/GO?
Or any ideas why the page throws a 404 but loads fine when hitting ENTER?

Also, I cant use window.open or window.location.href="new url here" because I need to POST params.

Thanks

Comment: window.open(HERE GOES THE URL, "_blank")

Comment: cant use window.open or window.location.href because I need to POST params

Comment: Your target page is refusing the POST but accepting the GET.

Comment: ah yes, I think you may be right.

Comment: that was it! thanks